# How to override a template for a custom field in symfony (for edit in easyadmin)

Tags: symfony, twig, easyadmin, a2lix-translation

I use A2lix for translation and I use easyadmin. I created a "TranslationField" :

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Controller\Admin\Field;

use A2lix\TranslationFormBundle\Form\Type\TranslationsType;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Contracts\Field\FieldInterface;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\FieldTrait;

final class TranslationField implements FieldInterface
{
    use FieldTrait;

    public static function new(string $propertyName, ?string $label = null, array $fieldsConfig = []): self
    {
        return (new self())
            ->setProperty($propertyName)
            ->setTemplatePath('admin/field/translation_field.html.twig')
            ->setTemplateName('translation_field')
            ->setLabel($label)
            ->setFormType(TranslationsType::class)
            ->setFormTypeOptions([
                'default_locale' => 'fr',
                'fields' => $fieldsConfig,
            ]);
    }
```

In my EntityCrudController.php, I use this TranslationField

```
public function configureCrud(Crud $crud): Crud
{
        return $crud
            ->setEntityLabelInSingular('Product')
            ->setEntityLabelInPlural('Products')
            ->setPageTitle("index", "Admin product")
            ->setPaginatorPageSize(20)
            ->addFormTheme('@FOSCKEditor/Form/ckeditor_widget.html.twig');
}

public function configureFields(string $pageName): iterable
{

yield TranslationField::new('translations', ' ', [
       'name' => [ 
           'field_type' => TextType::class,
           'required' => true,
           'label' => 'Name of the product FR',
           'locale_options' => [
               'fr' => ['label' => 'Name of the product FR'],
               'en' => ['label' => 'Name of the product EN'],
               'es' => ['label' => 'Name of the product ES'],
               'it' => ['label' => 'Name of the product IT'],
               'de' => ['label' => 'Name of the product DE'],
                ], 
             ]
])
 ->setTemplatePath('admin/field/translation_field.html.twig')
 ->hideOnIndex();
[...]

}
```

My twig template "translation_field.html.twig" is to have tabs with languages :

```
{# @var ea \EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Context\AdminContext #}
{# @var field \EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Dto\FieldDto #}
{# @var entity \EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Dto\EntityDto #}
{% set render_as_html = field.customOptions.get('renderAsHtml') %}

</dd></div></dl>
<div class="data-row">
<ul class="nav nav-tabs w-100 border-bottom-0" role="tablist">

    {% set myArray = field.value|toArray %}
    {% for key_langue, valueObject in myArray['collection'] %}
        <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
            <a id="{{ key_langue|upper }}-home-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#{{ key_langue|upper }}-home" class="border-bottom nav-link{% if key_langue == app.request.locale %} active{% endif %}" href="#{{ key_langue }}-tab" aria-controls="{{ key_langue }}-tab" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
                {{ key_langue|upper }}
            </a>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
[...]
```

When I see the detail of my home, it's OK, this is my template "translation_field.html.twig" which is used.
[Detail: my template is used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eF8st.png)

When I click on "edit", this is not my template, this is the standard template of easyadmin for the field and I don't have tabs with all the languages.
[Edit: my template is not used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e10ll.png)

I've read the symfony doc and try to understand why my template is not used when I edit. It seems that my template should be used on detail and edit with the code ->setTemplatePath('admin/field/translation_field.html.twig')

How to define to use my template for this field when editing my entity in easyadmin ?

Answer (score 0):

I know this question was asked a while ago, but I wanted to provide an answer for those who may still be struggling with it.

To override a template for a custom field, you can call the `addFormTheme()` method in the custom field. For example:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Controller\Admin\Field;

use A2lix\TranslationFormBundle\Form\Type\TranslationsType;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Contracts\Field\FieldInterface;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\FieldTrait;

final class TranslationField implements FieldInterface
{
    use FieldTrait;

    public static function new(string $propertyName, ?string $label = null, array $fieldsConfig = []): self
    {
        return (new self())
            ->setProperty($propertyName)
            ->addFormTheme('admin/crud/form/field/translations.html.twig')
            ->setTemplatePath('admin/field/translation_field.html.twig')
            ->setTemplateName('translation_field')
            ->setLabel($label)
            ->setFormType(TranslationsType::class)
            ->setFormTypeOptions([
                'default_locale' => 'fr',
                'fields' => $fieldsConfig,
            ]);
    }
}
```

I have also written a [detailed guide](https://dzhebrak.com/blog/translating-entities-easyadmin-doctrinebehaviors) about using A2lix and DoctrineBehaviors for translation in EasyAdmin, which includes a section on theming.